# Javascript how to check if a node has a ul childnode and copy a link of another node

Tags: javascript

hello in the code below:

```
<li id="ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMap_rptUniverses_ctl01_liUniverse" class="open"> <a href="/vp4/_spen/Ar/bufi/g_H048BNV54/ikDirId1877137.aspx"><span>Chemises</span></a>

    <ul class="subMenuEV">
        <li id="ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMap_rptUniverses_ctl01_rptSubUniverses_ctl01_liSubUniverse"><span class="selected">fwtk</span>
        </li>
        <li id="ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMap_rptUniverses_ctl01_rptSubUniverses_ctl02_liSubUniverse"><a href="/vp4/sk/fwtk/bufi/FR_H0848BNV54/ikDirId1897197.aspx">Chemises à micro-carreaux</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMap_rptUniverses_ctl01_rptSubUniverses_ctl03_liSubUniverse"><a href="/vp4/sk/fwtk/bufi/FR_H0848BNV54/ikDirId1877140.aspx">Chemises à carreaux</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMap_rptUniverses_ctl01_rptSubUniverses_ctl04_liSubUniverse"><a href="/vp4/sk/fwtk/bufi/FR_H0848BNV54/ikDirId1877139.aspx">Chemises à rayures</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMap_rptUniverses_ctl01_rptSubUniverses_ctl05_liSubUniverse"><a href="/vp4/sk/fwtk/bufi/FR_H0848BNV54/ikDirId1877141.aspx">Chemises à motifs</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMap_rptUniverses_ctl01_rptSubUniverses_ctl06_liUniverseViewAll"><a href="/vp4/sk/fwtk/bufi/FR_H0848BNV54/ikDirId1877137.aspx?cypher=thFzt%2FLPQalbsRRg1P5UUQ%3D%3D">Tous les produits disponibles</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I would like to check if the first **li** tag has a **ul** childnode , if it has ,then it should alert and say that ul exist and copy the link in the (**a**) **tag** below to a variable **lk**

```
/vp4/_spen/Ar/bufi/g_H048BNV54/ikDirId1877137.aspx
```

Can you please help me to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any framework such as jQuery or do you require a plain-JS solution?

Comment: Is the 'first' `li` tag the one that contains the `ul` (in this example)? And which of the `a` tags should it be copying *from*, there's quite a few. Incidentally, for demos, it's probably best to use less verbose `id` names (to reduce the scope of typos in answers).

Comment: Yes first li contains the ul and i want to copy the a tag that contains the link /vp4/_spen/Ar/bufi/g_H048BNV54/ikDirId1877137.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.querySelector("#ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMa_rptUniverses_stl01_liUniverse > ul")) { // Does the li in the question have an ul inside it?
    alert(document.querySelector("#ctl00_altColumnContent_universeMa_rptUniverses_stl01_liUniverse > a").href) // Is so, print out the href of the a.
}
```

Explanation in comments. (Scroll right to see them. Your ID is a tad long.)